# Выдает ошибку об инициализации font

Tags: python, pygame

Сделал класс кнопки вроде все правильно, но почему- то пайтон выдает вот такую ошибку

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ITVDN\PYTHON\pythonProject\bookPractic\pygame\rocket\main.py", line 33, in <module>
    run()
  File "D:\ITVDN\PYTHON\pythonProject\bookPractic\pygame\rocket\main.py", line 20, in run
    play_button = Button(r_setting, screen, "Play")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\ITVDN\PYTHON\pythonProject\bookPractic\pygame\rocket\button.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 48)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pygame.error: font not initialized

Process finished with exit code 1

pygame.error: font not initialized
```

Код напишу ниже, подскажите что не так, почему выдает такую ошибку. Указывал и полный пусть, и указывал просто название шрифта , ничего не помогло

```
import pygame.font


class Button:
    def __init__(self, r_settings, screen, msg):
        
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        # Назначение размеров и свойств кнопок.
        self.width, self.height = 400, 200
        self.button_color = (0, 255, 0)
        self.text_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
        # Построение объекта rect кнопки и выравнивание по центру экрана.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center
        # Сообщение кнопки создается только один раз.
        self.prep_msg(msg)

    def prep_msg(self, msg):

        self.msg_image = self.font.render(msg, True, self.text_color, self.button_color)
        self.msg_image_rect = self.msg_image.get_rect()
        self.msg_image_rect.center = self.rect.center

    def draw_button(self):

        self.screen.fill(self.button_color, self.rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.msg_image, self.msg_image_rect)
```

Comment: Что говориться в ошибке? Почему вы не используете более современный модуль `pygame.freetype`?

Comment: Ошибку,  добавил, сверху. Попробовал вы советовали, выдает ошибку , что freetype  не инициализирован. А установить, что-то не получается

Comment: font not initialized, что значит?

Comment: Вот и я хочу узнать, вроде всё записал как надо, а оно мне выдает ошибку и всё

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался,с трудом но получилось, в функции запуска `run()` нужно было написать `pygame.init()`, но опять назревает вопрос, эта инициализация есть в функции `check_evens()` ,  но если она  там стоит, тогда ошибка, а перенес ее в `run()` и все заработало

Comment: pygame.init(), также как и pygame.font.init() всегда надо располагать на верхнем уровне приложения, в главном модуле, содержащим основной цикл игры, один раз, а не где-то внутри функций несколько раз. Посмотрите структуру любого проекта pygame

Comment: Ну теперь и буду так делать, просто делал по примеру книги, ещё сам удивился зачем было нужно засовывать в функцию, но теперь будет уроком